# How to ensure that two programs always run ? (where the one depends upon the other.)

Tags: windows-xp, login

I need to run two programs. One depends on the other for information during it's execution. I therefore need to ensure the first is started before the second runs. Furthermore I need the programs to run the entire time I m logged on.

I initially thought I could do this with windows services. Services allows me to specify the dependency but it prevents the programs for running as they both have user interfaces. is there some other way to get this going. I'm using a Batch script for now which is hardly a good means of doing this as it only calls the programs when I log on but not if they crash.

I can't recompile/edit the programs to make them talk to a service either.

It's ok for these programs to only start once the user has logged on. I don't need them to run if the user has not logged on.

Comment: You will have to design your own program to verify the programs are running if the method your using does not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with with a .bat file or similar (although you don't like it, read on :) ).

Get your batch file to first check if the program(s) are running and if not, then load then up!

```
@echo off

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq dependantProgram.exe" | find /i "dependantProgram.exe" 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 start "" "C:\Program Files\dependantProgram.exe"
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myProgram.exe" | find /i "myProgram.exe" 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 start "" "C:\Program Files\dependantProgram.exe"
```

Now, have task scheduler run this when a user logs on, and execute every X minutes.

Comment: I'm not opposed to a batch file, I just have to suppress itas you have. Is there a way to make the batch file call itself in a few minutes instead of the scheduler ? This is more out of interest then anything else. If the program starts but reports an error message to the user would this register as a closed program ? or does that depend on the application's error handling.

Comment: Only if you put it into a loop! I guess, but this would mean you always had the command console on screen which is pretty grim!  :)

Comment: That is depressingly grim :| (P.s. how many chess jokes do you get about your surname ? Mine is van Dam so bank clerks keep Karate Chopping their counters)